# How to set multiple environment variables from output of other command in bash?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, git-bash

I set a variable that contains multiple values. (this is what I get from `heroku config --shell`, redacted)
The command to save command output was

```sh
envvars=`heroku config --shell -a heroku-app`
```

And `echo "$envvars"` result is like this:

```
BH_SERVER=000000000000000000
DATABASE_URL='postgres://stringno1:randomstring1@someserver.com:5432/randomstring2'
DISCORD_TOKEN=some.veryveryveryvery.long.token.string
EXM_SERVER=000000000000000001
MUTED_SERVER='000000000000000002, 000000000000000003'
SUPER_USER='000000000000000004, 000000000000000005'
TEST_SERVER=000000000000000006
TZ=Asia/Seoul
```

Now I want to set these values to environment variables. These **must not** be permanant because these are only needed by python app which will be executed later in script. I think I can use `=` as delimiter for distinguish key and value but not 100% sure about that. (I don't know how heroku convar works well)

I expect these-like output.

```sh
echo $BH_SERVER
# 000000000000000000
echo $DATABASE_URL
# postgres://stringno1:randomstring1@someserver.com:5432/randomstring2
# Note that there is no ' in start and end of line
echo $DISCORD_TOKEN
# some.veryveryveryvery.long.token.string
# Note that . is still there.
echo $MUTED_SERVER
# 000000000000000002, 000000000000000003
# Even if there is space in string, it should be treated as one line
# Also, there is no ' in start and end of line
echo $TZ
# Asia/Seoul
# / is not interpreted. I think this is normal.
```

There are some already-answered question but I don't find any answer that match my condition.

I put `git-bash` tag because I am working on Git Bash but I think solution of this question would be same as Bash.

Comment: did you try eval $envvars?

Comment: @Lety you mean `eval $envvar`? that just stops script working. I think it is waiting user input but not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `eval`. Make sure to use the double quotes or else the settings with spaces and quotes will get mangled.

```
eval "$envvars"
```

or

```
eval "$(heroku config --shell -a heroku-app)"
```

You can use a subshell to isolate the changes to a section of code.

```
# Parentheses create a subshell, or child process.
# Variables set in a child process don't affect the parent.
(
    eval "$(heroku config --shell -a heroku-app)"
    echo "$BH_SERVER"
    echo "$DATABASE_URL"
    echo "$DISCORD_TOKEN"
    echo "$MUTED_SERVER"
    echo "$TZ"
)

# The variables will be unset here.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add echo output to temporary file, source the file and then delete the temp file
:

`echo $envvars > /tmp/tmp.env && source /tmp/tmp.env && rm /tmp/tmp.env`

If on gitbash /tmp is not available, use another available path to create the temporary file

Alternately you can use below format which will not need temporary file

`echo $envvars | source /dev/stdin`

Comment: surprisingly, it works! I don't like concept of 'creating new temporary file' but it works. I wonder is there any way to not create 'temporary' files though... Thanks anyway.

Comment: I have modified the answer, Can you try the second format without the temp file "echo $envvars | source /dev/stdin"

Comment: The second one won't work. Pipelines run in subshells.

Comment: second method doesn't work. `git-bash` seems don't like `/dev/stdin` stuff. Anyway, it seems `git-bash` seems using Windows' own temporary directory(`%temp%`) which is nice to know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but this should work

```sh
eval $(echo $envvars) ./script.sh
```

or

```sh
eval $(echo $envvars) python script.py
```

Comment: both doesn't work neither. it says 'not a valid identifier' when processing `'0000, 0000'`-like lines

Comment: I've updated the anwer to address this case